# How do I keep one portion of the query string in the URL when going to another page using Django?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm creating a web app that does web crawling using `Django`. After clicking a button the crawling would start. After the crawling process is done, I would get a query string like this

`?conditions=cancer&geolocation=&startdate=2019-05-10&enddate=2019-05-11&max=100`

I would like to know how can I get the button to auto redirect to the next page while keeping the query string in the URL intact? Preferably without any new packages or new coding language if possible.

At the moment, i'm using two buttons one for crawling and one to bring the user to the next page but this method doesn't keep the query string in the URL intact.

Thanks!

I have tried adding `action="/view"` into form in crawl.html, however it would just immediately direct the user to the next page and stop the crawling process.

Button `onclick` does the same thing as well. It brings the user to the next page and cuts short the crawling process.

in **views.py**

```py
class testcrawl(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'crawl.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # crawl codes

        return tweets
```

in **crawl.html**

```html
<form method="GET">
  //multiple input fields (not using django forms)
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="searched">Search</button>
```

Comment: Have you considered using django's built-in pagination?

Comment: @cagrias The URL query string that I would like to keep intact is not part of models.py. It's more of the conditions of what I want to crawl. If that's the case would Django's built-in pagination still be applicable to keep the URL intact?